# SVG Animation - stroke-dashoffset behaving differently in Chrome and in FF

Tags: html, animation, svg

So I was working on this animation http://codepen.io/rezen/pen/vEgqs and at the bottom you can see the properties for an animation on a path

```
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="600;0" begin="0s" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

In Chrome the animation is an appropriate speed, however in FireFox it move very fast. If I change the `values="600;0"` to something smaller like `values="60;0"` then in FireFox it looks correct however in Chrome it animates very slow.

What is happening?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Firefox 18 seems to do it perfectly. (It looks like the conveyor belt is very slightly too slow, but that's consistent with Chromium.)

Comment: Like OP, I do have different behaviors for the conveyor belt speeds, with Firefox going too fast and backward. FF 19.0a2 vs Chrome 23.0.

Comment: Opera 12.10, Firefox 19.0a1 and Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94 all looked the same to me (correct with 600).

Comment: Hmmm so I just tried on FF 17.01 on my Mac and it worked correctly. It seems to be a difference in Windows vs Mac?